# Angular/Firebase Web App - What's the best practice to handle asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's imagine a Web App developed with Angular and Firebase.
In this app, there is a page with a list of public events (retrieved from Firebase) displayed as a list of switch elements.
The user can register/unregister to each event by toggling the switch and it automatically updates his own list of events he is registered to (ng-change on each switch that update the user Firebase db).

So I created a Database service:

```
//private
var eventList = [];
// methods
this.getEventList = function(){
    if(eventList.length > 0){
        console.info('[getEventList] Event list already fetched');
        return eventList;
    }
    else{
        console.info('[getEventList] Event list has never been fetched');
        this.loadEventList();
    }
}
this.loadEventList = function(){
    console.info('[LoadEventList] Fetch event list');
    var events = [];
    firebase.database().ref('events/').once('value').then(function(snap) {
        snap.forEach(function(item) {
            events.push({
                id: item.val().id,
                name: item.val().name,
                registered: false
            });
        });
        console.info('[LoadEventList] End of fetching');
        console.dir(events);
        eventList = events;
        return eventList;
    });
}
```

And a User Service in which I wrote a function that allows to synchronize the list of the event the user is registered to with the global list of public events. I want to display the full list of public events and the switchs to be toggled based on the registrations the user as made:

```
this.syncEventListWithUserEventss = function(listToSync){
    userRef.child('events/').once('value', function(snap){
        var userEvents = snap.val();

        // sync only if user registered at least one event
        if(userEvents) {
            for(var i = 0; i < userEvents.length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < listToSync.length; j++){
                    if(listToSync[j].id ==userEvents[i]){
                        listToSync[j].registered = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My code is working fine so far. but it gets tricky in the page controller:

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, DatabaseService, UserService) {
    $scope.events = [];
    console.info('[Ctrl] Before getEventList()');
    console.dir($scope.events);

    $scope.events = DatabaseService.getEventList();
    console.info('[Ctrl] After getEventList()');
    console.dir($scope.events);

    UserService.syncEventListWitEventports($scope.events);

    $scope.updateUserEventList = UserService.updateUserEventList;
}])
```

Results:

```
[Ctrl] Before getEventList()
Array[0]

[getEventList] Event list has never been fetched
[LoadEventList] Fetch event list

[Ctrl] After getEventList()
undefined

[LoadEventList] End of fetching
Array[4]
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is my first call (getEventList) blocking ? And that would mean that console.info('[Ctrl] After getEventList()'); don't get executed until getEventList() is finished?
2. How do I make my call to loadEventList() blocking so that my controller doesn't execute any further code until the event list is completely loaded and passed to the controller
3. What are the best practices for those kind of needs

Thank you!

Comment: by using callback or return Promise

Comment: Isn't what I am doing by calling loadEventList in which the return statement is nested in a promise? Any concrete solution in my case? Thanks

Comment: you are consuming a promise in loadEventList, but that function does not return anything, better pass a callback there.

Comment: callback approach - `this.getEventList = function(cb){` / `this.loadEventList(cb);` / `this.loadEventList = function(cb){` / `return eventList;` to `cb(eventList);` / `DatabaseService.getEventList(function(data) {$scope.events = data; });`

Comment: Works better, indeed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> return statement is nested in a promise? Any concrete solution in my case?

When the success handler furnished as an argument to a `.then` method has a return statement, a derived promise can be returned to the parent function.

```
this.loadEventList = function(){
    console.info('[LoadEventList] Fetch event list');
    var events = [];

    //retain promise
    var promise = firebase.database().ref('events/').once('value');
    //retain derived promise
    var derivedPromise = promise.then(function(snap) {
        snap.forEach(function(item) {
            events.push({
                id: item.val().id,
                name: item.val().name,
                registered: false
            });
        });
        console.info('[LoadEventList] End of fetching');
        console.dir(events);
        eventList = events;
        //return to chain data
        return eventList;
    });
    //return to parent function
    return derivedPromise;
};
```

The promise returned can be used to hold a function for later processing

```
this.loadEventList().then(function successHandler(eventList) {
    //Put further processing here
    console.log(eventList);
});
```

Functions furnished to the `.then` method are held by `$q` service until the asynchronous operation resolves. This is the accepted best practice in AngularJS for handling asynchronous operations.